# JAVA Serialization always has a null element in my array

Tags: java, json, jackson

fairly new to this serializing/deserializng stuff and have been stuck trying to figure out why the object is being serialized with a null element on the array.

1. Using a generic json string I'm deserializing it into my object A.
2. Then using the generic ObjectMapper I'm converting that object A to its string value via objectMapper.writeValueAsString()
3. The value returned ALWAYS comes back with

   ```
   {
       [
           {[correct stuff]},
           null
       ]
   }
   ```

I'm losing my mind here as to how the **null** is being added in here. I've tried countless configurations with the objectMapper as well as altering all classes involved with

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false)
```

Can anyone educate me on how to prevent the null from being added to my array?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Could you share the structure of Class A?

Comment: Please share your raw json.

Comment: We can't explain and fix your code if you don't post your code.

Comment: The code is on another system not connected to the network. I'm dealing with dozens of POJOs so litterally thousands of lines of code and am traversing through all of the objects tracing down each json property to its equivalent. I was just now after many hours of this hoping for a silver bullet solution. This does not appear to be an item to be resolved here since I cannot post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because all array items are all relevant. You cannot just remove an item in the middle of an array. If an array has at least one element, including null, it will still be written out because it is not empty.

Non-null usually refers to key-value pairs (in an object) where the value is null. This will tell the marshaller to ignore the pair entirely.

You will need to programatically filter-out the null item in the array after you deserialize your JSON.

#### Breakdown

```
myArray : null   // (Ignore)      null
myArray : []     // (Ignore)  not-null &     empty
myArray : [null] // (Include) not-null & not-empty
```

---

Using a custom JsonSerializer.

### StringArraySerializer (Serializer)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

// Derived from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18645677
public class StringArraySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, Object value) {
        String[] arr = (String[]) value;
        return arr == null || arr.length == 0 || (arr.length == 1 && arr[0] == null);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String[] arr = (String[]) value;
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        for (String item : arr) {
            if (item != null) {
                jgen.writeString(item);
            }
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

### App (Driver)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

public class App {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false); // Deprecated

            Info[] list = {
                new Info("Array contains null.", new String[] { "foo", null, "bar" }),
                new Info("Array only contains null.", new String[] { null }),
                new Info("Array is empty.", new String[] { }),
                new Info("Array is null.", null)
            };

            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(list));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Info (POJO)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Info {
    private String description;

    @JsonSerialize(using = StringArraySerializer.class)
    private String[] items;

    public Info(String description, String[] items) {
        super();
        this.description = description;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(String[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

### Output

```
[ {
  "description" : "Array contains null.",
  "items" : [ "foo", "bar" ]
}, {
  "description" : "Array only contains null."
}, {
  "description" : "Array is empty."
}, {
  "description" : "Array is null."
} ]
```

### Dependencies (Gradle)

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0.pr1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0.pr1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0.pr1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because a null may be part of the array. Consider a simple array of objects [1, null, 2, 'github'].

When you serialize and deserialize it, you will want to preserve the null entry. There are other scenarios also but they might be irrelevant without looking at your full code.

Hope this helps.